# How to  print data from Android app to WIFI printer?

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi

I am developing shopping cart application in Android 2.1 . I want to print the order details ( customer details , cart details, order total) , when user submit the order . I want to use some WIFI printer for printing the data. Please help me with suitable examples ...

Comment: . Please give me any idea printing using  WIFI printer from Android app ...

Comment: how to send a pdf file from android to wifi printer programatically?

Comment: Have you get the solution @Anoop

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to print on receipt-sized paper. If so, Star Micronics has an Android SDK with support for Wifi connections as well as USB and Bluetooth. Download it here: http://starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx

If you're looking for a regular size printer, check out Google Cloud Print: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/?hl=en

Comment: Hi, thanks but do you know if this SDK is just for Star printers or it's generic for other brands of printers? I'm trying to connect my printer throught that SDK and it seems impossible for me

Answer (score 0):

Create a Socket connection from ip address and port number.

```
 String ip = "your printer ip address";
 int port = port number; 

private class printTCP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              
                if (!ip.equals("")) {
                    if ((pref.getString(Const.PORT_CASH) != null) && (!pref.getString(Const.PORT_CASH).equals(""))) {
                        port = Integer.parseInt(pref.getString(Const.PORT_CASH));
                        try {
                            client = new Socket(ip, port);// ip address and port number of ur hardware device
                            String text = "Test Print";
                            byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(); //create a byte array 
                           
                            outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
    
                            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                            client.close();
    
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                return null;
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    
            }
        }
```